# Programming Puzzles & Code Golf throws an error on the Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Although the Stack Exchange Data Explorer is an invaluable tool for many, it appears that the [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) site is [throwing an error upon querying](https://data.stackexchange.com/programming%20puzzles%20&%20code%20golf%20stack%20exchange/queries). It appears to me to be a result of the ampersand `&` in the URL. As code golf is one of my favorite activities on Stack Exchange, I would like to see this fixed sometime soon, or an alternative link to access the data

Comment: Yep, already in the process of being fixed.

Comment: TIL SEDE now includes beta sites. Awesome!

Comment: @TimStone Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Timtech Tim Stone _is_ the reference when it comes to SEDE.

Comment: @Yannis [As of an hour ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216245/172958)

Comment: @Yannis Okay, thanks. I'm unfamiliar with Data Explorer and SE's developers. (Not for long!)

Comment: @Timtech See https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer

Comment: @TimStone If you're hacking that part of the code, could you [remove the spaces as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197234/data-stackexchange-com-site-urls-contain-spaces)? In fact it would be nice to have the same name in the API and on SEDE.

Comment: @Gilles Yeah, that's the ultimate fix which should be done later today. We'll see if it's worth just fixing those site names as a stopgap measure while I do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's worth noting that this has been temporarily fixed by [Nick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver), since all ampersands* have been replaced by "and", the ampersand being an illegal path character which caused the site to choke.

I've now also [converted the URLs](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/23) to use the API/domain-preferred name anyway, as [Gilles mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216254/programming-puzzles-code-golf-throws-an-error-on-the-data-explorer#comment699891_216254) in the comments. This seems like the saner way to construct those URLs, and has the added benefit of not falling prey to unexpected characters in site names. As always, this is pending a pull and redeploy of Data Explorer.

<sub>*The use of which is inconsistent across site titles, but I digress</sub>