# Include the site name as text on the SEDE home page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

The home page of the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) lists all the sites.

Let's say I want to navigate to a particular site. So I search on the page, let's say, “unix”. No match. Weird, I was pretty sure we had a [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site. And what about that “server” site? Only has a meta?¹ “Home improvement”? “Overflow” as in Math or Stack? “Electrical” or “engineering”? (Exercise: without visiting another web page, find [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) in that list.)

The name of the site is only provided as a logo, with the site's description as a subtitle. Please include it in searchable form.

¹  <sub>Two metas, actually — the description for MSO is “Q&A about Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User”, which is in serious need of updating.</sub>

Comment: As a sidenote the homepage is getting a redesign anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll leave the description-fixing to someone else, but provided there's no complaints, I've [redesigned the homepage](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/25) to include the site name as text and use the touch icons, which are more compact and don't suffer from theming issues when being displayed on that page.

Pending a pull and redeploy, it'll look like this:

[image: redesigned Data Explorer homepage]

Comment: Thanks! Any chance of [the URLs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197234/data-stackexchange-com-site-urls-contain-spaces) being sanitized?

Comment: Oh, yes, I did that already (it's a pending pull request still). I'll put an answer on that question here in a bit.